# Getting 401 Unauthorized making API call with access token (.Net WebApi / React.js Visual Studio templated project)

Tags: reactjs, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, authorization

I have created a React.js project using the supplied template in Visual studio that also uses WebApi (with individual account authentication/authorization) and controllers. I am able to create an account and log in without issue, but when I attempt to access an API endpoint (/user in this case) with a token received from the MS AuthorizationServices.js GetAccessToken(), I continually get 401 Unauthorized responses. Occasionally when I restart the project and login, it works without issue.

I created the /user controller since I extended the base IdentityUser model to include a StravaAthleteId property that is needed for the project I'm working on.  The endpoint works fine when called with a valid token, but in this component it doesn't seem to be getting or using a valid token, although one is returned from the authService.getAccessToken() method called in populateState(). The browser dev tools show: Www-Authenticate:
Bearer error="invalid_token" in the /user fetch call Response Headers section.

Here is the code for the main component that gets returned on startup. It always return the "You need to connect your Strava account" markup, even though the webAppUser in the DB has a StravaAthleteId and I'm authenticated. I have not really fussed with any of the out of the box authorization endpoints or helpers:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import authService from "../api-authorization/AuthorizeService";
import { WebAppUser } from "./models/webAppUser";
import { ApplicationPaths } from "../api-authorization/ApiAuthorizationConstants";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

function SegmentSniper() {
  const [userName, setUsername] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const loginPath = `${ApplicationPaths.Login}`;
  const [appUser, setAppUser] = useState<WebAppUser>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const _subscription = authService.subscribe(() => populateState());
    populateState();

    return () => {
      authService.unsubscribe(_subscription);
    };
  });

  async function populateState() {
    const [isAuthenticated, user] = await Promise.all([
      authService.isAuthenticated(),
      authService.getUser(),
    ]);
    setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated);
    setUsername(user && user.name);
    console.log(`user from populate state = ${JSON.stringify(user, null, 4)}`);
    const authToken = await authService
      .getAccessToken()
      .then((res) => console.log(`user token: ${res}`));
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/user", {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(`There was an error fetching the user data.`);
      } else {
        response
          .json()
          .then((resolvedData) => setAppUser(resolvedData))
          .catch((error) =>
            console.log(`There was an error fetching the user data. ${error}`)
          );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`There was an error fetching the data. ${error}`);
    }
  }

  return !isAuthenticated ? (
    <>
      <main className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
          <div className="col-6">
            <p>You must be logged in to access this app.</p>
            <p>
              Click
              <Link to={loginPath}> here </Link>
              to login.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  ) : isAuthenticated && !appUser?.stravaAthleteId ? (
    <>
      <main className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
          <div className="col-6">
            <p>You need to connect your Strava Account.</p>
            <p>
              Click
              <Link to={loginPath}>
                {" "}
                <img src=".\assets\stravaImages\btn_strava_connectwith_orange\btn_strava_connectwith_orange.png" />{" "}
              </Link>
              to get started.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      <main className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center mt-3 mb-3">
          <div className="main-tile">
            <ul>
              <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                <Link to="./athlete">View Athlete Details</Link>
              </li>
              <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                <Link to="./activities">Segment Sniper</Link>
              </li>
              <li style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
                <Link to="./token-maintenance">Token Maintenance</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            
            <h3>webappuser: {appUser?.id}</h3>
            <h3>stravaAthleteId: {appUser?.stravaAthleteId}</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export default SegmentSniper;
```

Here is the user controller:

```
namespace StravaSegmentSniper.React.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebAppUserService _webAppUserService;
        private readonly UserManager<WebAppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public UserController(IWebAppUserService webAppUserService, UserManager<WebAppUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _webAppUserService = webAppUserService;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public WebAppUser GetUser()
        {
            var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString();
             var user = _webAppUserService.GetLoggedInUserById(userId);
            return user;
        }
```

This is the program.cs for the project:

```
using StravaSegmentSniper.React.Helpers;

//var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var builder = WebAppBuilderConfig.ConfigureBuilder();

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html"); ;


app.Run();
```

and here is the WebAppBuilderConfig that it calls at the top:

```
using Authorization.Data.Data;
using Authorization.Data.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Data;
using StravaSegmentSniper.React.ActionHandlers.Activity;
using StravaSegmentSniper.React.ActionHandlers.Segment;
using StravaSegmentSniper.React.ActionHandlers.StravaApiToken;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.Internal.Adapters;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.Internal.Services;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.StravaAPI.Activity;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.StravaAPI.Athlete;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.StravaAPI.Segment;
using StravaSegmentSniper.Services.StravaAPI.TokenService;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Text;

namespace StravaSegmentSniper.React.Helpers
{
    public class WebAppBuilderConfig
    {
        public static WebApplicationBuilder ConfigureBuilder()
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();


            var authConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthorizationData");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(authConnectionString));
            builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<WebAppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();

            builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<WebAppUser, AuthDbContext>();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            var appDataConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StravaSegmentSniperData");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<StravaSegmentSniperDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(appDataConnectionString).UseLazyLoadingProxies());

            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            //builder.Services.AddRouting(ctx => ctx.LowercaseUrls = false);

            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "JWTToken_Auth_API",
                    Version = "v1"
                });
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer 1safsfsdfdfd\"",
                });
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                }
            },
            new string[] {}
        }
    });
            });

            builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

            //builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaSegmentSniperDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<StravaSegmentSniperDbContext>());

            //add DI services to the container
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAthleteActivityService, AthleteActivityService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IAthleteService, AthleteService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaTokenService, StravaTokenService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IWebAppUserService, WebAppUserService>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaAPIAthlete, StravaAPIAthlete>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaAPIActivity, StravaAPIActivity>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaAPISegment, StravaAPISegment>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaAPIToken, StravaAPIToken>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IActivityAdapter, ActivityAdapter>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<ISegmentAdapter, SegmentAdapter>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaActivityActionHandler, StravaActivityActionHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaApiTokenActionHandler, StravaApiTokenActionHandler>();
            builder.Services.AddScoped<IStravaSegmentActionHandler, StravaSegmentActionHandler>();

            return builder;
        }



    }
}
```

and here is when the app runs and I have logged in:
[app running showing auth error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAh8O.png)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with calling the /user endpoint with either an expired token, or one that was not from a valid issuer. The tokens were fine, I just had to update the refreshing of them an trusting the issuer.